# Add prototype to existing object

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

I'd like to do some inheritance using Javascript. The problem is I don't know how to keep the A class prototype on the inherited object.

Here is my code :

```
function Base() {
    this.attribute1 = null;
}

Base.prototype = {
    baseFunction: function() {}
};

function SubBase()
{
    Base.call(this); // Constructor call
    this.baseFunction();
    this.subBaseFunction();
}

SubBase.prototype = Base.prototype;
SubBase.prototype = {
    subBaseFunction: function() {},
    subBaseOtherFunction: function() {}
}
```

With that way I erase `Base.prototype` but I don't want to.

I tried `SubBase.prototype.__proto__ = Base.prototype;` but [it is apparently too slow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

I know I can do (but too long to write and not that clean for me) :

```
SubBase.prototype.subBaseFunction = function() {};
SubBase.prototype.subBaseOtherFunction = function() {};
```

How can I do it/write it better ?

Comment: You might want to consider doing `SubBase.prototype = new Base();` instead of `SubBase.prototype = Base.prototype;`

Comment: I think I will use the last way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you aren't actually inheriting from Base... you're just adding functions to it.

```
SubBase.prototype = Base.prototype;
SubBase.prototype.foo = true;
alert(Base.prototype.foo);
```

To set up the inheritance chain, you need to assign an instance of base as the prototype:

```
SubBase.prototype = new Base();
```

Then you augment it, just like you have in your post:

```
SubBase.prototype.newFunction = function () { };
```

One weakness of doing inheritance this way is that your base class constructor can't receive arguments.  If you need that, then you need to use `Object.create` to set up the inheritance, and manually call your base class constructor:

```
function Base(x) {
    alert(x);
};
Base.prototype.baseFunction = function () {
    alert('called method from base class');
};

function SubBase(x) {
    Base.call(this, x);
};
SubBase.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);

var instance = new SubBase(1);
instance.baseFunction();
```

Comment: By doing `new Base()`, I also get object's attributes, how can I remove them from the prototype ?

Comment: If you don't want them inherited, don't add them to `Base.prototype` and don't set them inside of the constructor.  Unfortunately, passing arguments to base class constructors is not easy; you have to explicitly call that constructor

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to pass arguments to the base class constructor.

Comment: With `SubBase.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype)`, I'm inheriting from `Base` ?

Comment: Yes, you can test with `new SubBase(x).baseFunction()` - `baseFunction` is inherited.  I added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of this:

```
SubBase.prototype = Base.prototype;
SubBase.prototype = {
    subBaseFunction: function() {},
    subBaseOtherFunction: function() {}
}
```

you need to add each additional method onto the existing prototype object to avoid overwriting the `Base.prototype` you just put there:

```
// establish the prototype we're inheriting from
// make a new object into the prototype so when we change it, it 
// doesn't change the original
SubBase.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);

// now add more methods onto the inherited prototype
SubBase.prototype.subBaseFunction = function() {};
SubBase.prototype.subBaseOtherFunction = function() {};
```

Note: you also don't want to just assign `Base.prototype` because then when you change `SubBase.prototype`, you'll actually be changing both objects (an object assignment is just a reference).  So here, I'm using `Object.create(Base.prototype)` to create a copy of that prototype.

---

Many libraries support some sort of `extend()` function that copies properties from one object to another.  That lets you define a separate object of methods and then "add" it to the existing prototype, but this functionality isn't built-in to plain javascript.

For example in jQuery, you can do this:

```
// establish the prototype we're inheriting from
SubBase.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);

jQuery.extend(SubBase.prototype, {
    subBaseFunction: function() {},
    subBaseOtherFunction: function() {}
});
```

Or, **updated in 2016**, ES6 contains an [`Object.assign()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) that will copy properties from one object to another:

```
Object.assign(SubBase.prototype, {
    subBaseFunction: function() {},
    subBaseOtherFunction: function() {}
});
```

Or, you can make your own function that will copy properties from one object to another in only a few lines of code.

---

Or, the same code in plain javascript:

```
// copy properties from src to target
function copyProperties(target, src) {
    for (var prop in src) {
        if (src.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            target[prop] = src[prop];
        }
    }
    return(target);
}

// establish the prototype we're inheriting from
SubBase.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);

copyProperties(SubBase.prototype, {
    subBaseFunction: function() {},
    subBaseOtherFunction: function() {}
});
```

---

Here's the style I typically use:

```
function Base() {
    this.attribute1 = null;
}

Base.prototype = {
    baseFunction: function() {}
};

function SubBase()
{
    Base.apply(this, arguments); // Constructor call with arguments
}

(function() {
    var proto = SubBase.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
    proto.constructor = SubBase;
    proto.subBaseFunction = function() {
        // code here
    };
    proto.subBaseOtherFunction = function() {
        // code here
    };
})();
```

Comment: Yes I think it's the only way to make it work ! **Edit** : I won't use jQuery

Comment: @thomash - no problem on jQuery.  I was just illustrating an `extend()` type method that copies properties from one object to another.  It only takes about 10 lines of code to write such a function yourself - no need for jQuery to use that style.

Comment: @thomash - look at the style I typically use that I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Added `Object.assign()`, now present in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery.extend() for this:

```
SubBase.prototype = {
    subBaseFunction: function() {},
    subBaseOtherFunction: function() {}
};

$.extend(SubBase.prototype, Base.prototype);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/dd6UC/

jQuery.extend() docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/