# How can I inherit Carousel object in twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a new function to Bootstrap's Carousel's prototype. How can I do this?

Currently I am trying below

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel();

Carousel.prototype.myFunction = function () {
    // my logic goes here
};
```

But this does not work.

Comment: use this slider instead: http://www.idangero.us/swiper/ much better

Comment: Requirement is twitter bootstrap for my project.

Comment: just add, you won't regret, its easy to use and it comes with the perfect ux (;

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528841/add-prototype-to-existing-object

Comment: Wouldn't it be `$.Carousel.prototype.myFunction =`?